# how to create a session using cakephp (MVC)

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to know how to create session from my different users after they logged in, if there is a function please let me know.
my logg in function is :

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
                $this->Flash->error('Already logged in');
            } else {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl('/users/index'));

        }
        $this->Flash->error('Votre identifiant ou votre mot de passe est incorrect.');
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [chapter about sessions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html) in the manual?

Comment: You don't have to create the session manually. What exact problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **$this->Auth->setUser($user);** you log the user in, i.e., save user info to session.

You can access Session in CakePhp 3.x as

for user id:

> $this->request->Session()->read('Auth.User.id');